# Convert list of strings to variable names in order to create many filtered DataFrames dynamically

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a master DataFrame from which I want to create many filtered sub-frames, which I then want to pass to the ipyDataGrid widget and display in a VBOX later on. The number of sub-frames will vary and so I want to do this dynamically.

Example Master DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import ipydatagrid as ipd

data = {'ID': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'ASX', '489', 'KDO'],
       'Ret': [5, 7, 10, 6, 8, 99],
       'Sector': ['Banks', 'Banks', 'Automobiles', 'Media', 'Automobiles', 'Media']}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
frame = frame.set_index('ID')
frame
```

This provides output:

```
    Ret Sector
ID      
ABC 5   Banks
DEF 7   Banks
GHI 10  Automobiles
ASX 6   Media
489 8   Automobiles
KDO 99  Media
```

I have then created a unique_list of Sector names. In my real life example this is can be anything from 20-40 Sectors.

```
sector_names = frame['Sector'].unique()
```

And then from this list, I create the filtered sub-DataFrames:

```
for sector in sector_names:
    exec(f"{sector} = frame[frame['Sector']==sector].reset_index()")
```

This successfully created the sub-frames, for example:

```
Automobiles
```

Creates output:

```
    ID  Ret Sector
0   GHI 10  Automobiles
1   489 8   Automobiles
```

Passing the sub-Frame by name successfully creates a DataGrid:

```
ipd.DataGrid(dataframe=Automobiles)
```

But if I try the below I get an error (the idea from here is to create a for loop that appends the DataGrids for each sub-frame in the list sector_names to a VBOX).
I believe the reason for my error is my list is stored as strings, and I need to pass the sub-frame name variables. Can anyone help me convert the below to get this working dynamically?

```
ipd.DataGrid(dataframe=sector_names[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a way to do this with a dictionary.

```
test_dict = {'Banks': Banks,
         'Automobiles': Automobiles,
         'Media': Media}

test_dict[sector_names[1]]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Ret Sector
0   GHI 10  Automobiles
1   489 8   Automobiles
```

This now successfully returns the DataGrid.

```
ipd.DataGrid(dataframe=test_dict[sector_names[1]])
```